# How to remove duplicate tweets in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to retrieve about 1000 tweets from a search term like 'NFL' using tweepy and storing the tweets into a DataFrame using pandas. My issue is I can't find a way to remove duplicated tweets, I have tried df.drop_duplicates but it only gives me about 100 tweets to work with. Help would be appreciated!

```
num_needed = 1000
tweet_list = [] # Lists to be added as columns( Tweets, usernames, and screen names) in our dataframe 
user_list = []
screen_name_list = []
last_id = -1 # ID of last tweet seen
while len(tweet_list) < num_needed:
    try:
        new_tweets = api.search(q = 'NFL', count = num_needed, max_id = str(last_id - 1), lang = 'en', tweet_mode = 'extended') # This is the criteria for collecting the tweets that I want. I want to make sure the results are as accurate as possible when making a final analysis.
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error", e)
        break
    else:
        if not new_tweets:
            print("Could not find any more tweets!")
            break
        else:
            for tweet in new_tweets:

                # Fetching the screen name and username

                screen_name = tweet.author.screen_name
                user_name = tweet.author.name
  
                tweet_text = tweet.full_text
                tweet_list.append(tweet_text)
                user_list.append(user_name)
                screen_name_list.append(screen_name)

        
df = pd.DataFrame()  #Create a new dataframe (df) with new columns 
df['Screen name'] = screen_name_list
df['Username'] = user_list
df['Tweets'] = tweet_list
```

Comment: you can check `if tweet_text not in tweet_list: tweet_list.append(tweet_text)` You can also use `tweet_text.lower()` to make sure you compare lower case text.

Comment: This is the error i get when i try that:  Length of values (1001) does not match length of index (1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, when you use `.drop_duplicates()`, you only get 100 tweets because that's how many duplicates there are. Doesn't matter what technique you use here, there are 900 or so duplicates with how your code runs.

So you might be asking, why? It by default returns only 100 tweets, which I am assuming you are aware of since you are looping and you try to get more by using the `max_id` parameter. However, your `max_id`, is always `-1` here, you never get the `id` and thus never change that parameter. So one thing you can do, is while you iterate through the tweets, also collect the ids. Then after you get all the ids, store the minimum id value as `last_id`, then it'll work in your loop:

**Code:**

```
num_needed = 1000
tweet_list = [] # Lists to be added as columns( Tweets, usernames, and screen names) in our dataframe 
user_list = []
screen_name_list = []
tw_id = [] #<-- ADDED THIS
last_id = -1 # ID of last tweet seen
while len(tweet_list) < num_needed:
    try:
        new_tweets = api.search(q = 'NFL -filter:retweets', count = num_needed, max_id = str(last_id - 1), lang = 'en', tweet_mode = 'extended') # This is the criteria for collecting the tweets that I want. I want to make sure the results are as accurate as possible when making a final analysis.
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error", e)
        break
    else:
        if not new_tweets:
            print("Could not find any more tweets!")
            break
        else:
            for tweet in new_tweets:

                # Fetching the screen name and username

                screen_name = tweet.author.screen_name
                user_name = tweet.author.name
  
                tweet_text = tweet.full_text
                tweet_list.append(tweet_text)
                user_list.append(user_name)
                screen_name_list.append(screen_name)
                
                tw_id.append(tweet.id)  #<-- ADDED THIS
    last_id = min(tw_id)  #<-- ADDED THIS


df = pd.DataFrame({'Screen name':screen_name_list,
                   'Username':user_list,
                   'Tweets':tweet_list})
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

This returns to me aprox 1000 tweets.

**Output:**

```
print (len(df))
1084
```